# 'Char' type not converting to 'String' type as expected

Tags: java, if-statement, char, switch-statement, javascript-1.7

```
private boolean  CharToString(){
    String lineOfText = "XXXXXX";
    String desiredResult = "X";
    String actualResult = "initialised value";
    for(int i = 0; i < lineOfText.length(); i ++){
        actualResult = Character.toString(lineOfText.charAt(i));
        }
    if(desiredResult == actualResult){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

So basically, this code is a reproduction of what I have, but designed to highlight what I believe the problem to be after a long time diagnosing and testing.  As you can see, it sets the value of `actualResult` to the 'char' value of the character at the present location along `lineOfText`.
Every value is intended to output "X" as a String (converted from char).

However, for reasons unknown to me, despite `actualResult` and `desiredResult` both outputting "X" to my debug `drawText()` method (I can't work out how to use console log...), the method returns `false`, indicating that the two String variables are *NOT equal*.

Strangely, if I were to change the `if() else` to a `switch()`, it would return `true` (i.e. work as intended).

I've tried Googling and searching StackOverflow but my search terms are probably poor/wrong as I'm getting no useful results :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and sorry if this is a stupid question - I have tried for ages to figure it out myself...

*p.s.  Is there a good graphic map editor available online anywhere? Editing a .txt file to create a map seems overly complicated, and very difficult to maintain consistency or coherence in the development of large/intricate maps...  I figure there must be SOMETHING, how else would you make a 3D java game??*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't compare strings using `==`. Always use `equals()`, as `==` only compares that they point to the same memory address, which they won't in this case.

```
private boolean  CharToString(){
String lineOfText = "XXXXXX";
String desiredResult = "X";
String actualResult = "initialised value";
for(int i = 0; i < lineOfText.length(); i ++){
    actualResult = Character.toString(lineOfText.charAt(i));
    }
if(desiredResult.equals(actualResult)){
    return true;
} else{
    return false;
}
}
```

That should do it

Comment: Oh! Thank you!  ... if only Eclipse had come back with a warning about that.

Comment: @ZOMGbies Use Netbeans, you would have gotten that warning. :)

Answer (score 0):

To compare 2 strings that refer to different memory locations you should use:

```
if(desiredResult.equals(actualResult) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

If the case would have been:

```
String desiredResult = "test";
String actualResult = desiredResult;
```

In this case you could use `if(desiredResult == actualResult)` , but using `equals()` would be better practice.